# How to get from step A to step B in proof: mean of internal energy U of canoncial ensemble

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I'm struggling a lot figuring out how to go from step A to step B, it goes like this:

$$E=\langle U\rangle=\sum_{x} P(x) U(x)=\frac{1}{Z} \sum_{x} U(x) e^{-\frac{U(x)}{k_{B} T}} 
 \tag{A}$$
$$E=-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} \ln Z \quad \text { or } \quad \frac{\partial}{\partial T} \ln Z=\frac{E}{k_{B} T^{2}} \tag{B}$$
with $\beta=1 /\left(k_{B} T\right)$ and $Z=\sum_{x} e^{-\frac{U(x)}{k_{B} T}}$.

Extra info: $E$ is the mean of $U$ (internal energy), $P(x) =$ probability, $k_\mathrm B=$ Boltzmann constant and $T =$ temperature

I don't quit understand how you can simplify expression A with the use of partial derivatives, could somebody explain this to me.

Comment: With $\log$ you mean the natural logarithm? Have you tried to go from B to A?

Comment: Yes I mean the natural logarithm, I will adjust it. Thanks for noticing

Comment: @Jakob I strugling with the fact that there is a summation sign, so working from B to A is as difficult for me as vice versa

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Have you tried to rewrite the partial derivative of $\ln Z$ with the help of the chain rule? In other words: What is the derivative of $\ln f(x)$ with respect to $x$? The sum should not cause any trouble, since the partial derivative is linear, i.e. (roughly) the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives.

Comment: @Jakob Oh I see now, when you take te partial you get that $$-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}ln(z)=\sum_{x}U(x)$$, so you can fill that in and cancel Z so you can get E. Thank you so much I will try it for the partial with respect to T now!

Comment: It seems there are some things missing in the equation you gave. Anyway, if you think you found the answer to your problem, feel free write an answer on your own. It might help others in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128138/discussion-between-thecreator-and-jakob).

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it:

$$E = \sum_{x}U(x)P(x)$$
$$E = \sum_{x}U(x)\frac{1}{Z}e^{-\beta U(x)}$$
$$E = \frac{1}{Z}\sum_{x}U(x)\,e^{-\beta U(x)}$$
$$E = \frac{1}{Z}\left(-\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta}\sum_{x}e^{-\beta U(x)}\right)$$
$$E = \frac{1}{Z}\,\left(-\frac{\partial Z}{\partial \beta}\right)$$
$$E = -\frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial \beta}$$

Comment: There are errors. You can see this by simply comparing your last equation with your fourth equation. You have that $E = \sum\limits_x U(x)$. Try to use that $\partial_\beta \ln Z = \frac{ \partial_\beta Z}{Z}$. Then calculate  $ \partial_\beta Z$ using the linearity of the (partial) derivative.

Comment: Ok, thank you for responding I'll try and edit my answer

Comment: @Jakob I think I finally got it, could you check one last time just to be sure?

Comment: Yes, looks correct! Don't forget to accept your answer (if you want). In this way, the question is categorized as answered.